# PFQueryTableViewController text of cell issue

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

First, let me explain what it is that I am trying to do. I have three classes: User, Show and ShowAssignments. ShowAssignments has two relational columns, one that stores a Show and one that stores a User.

I have a PFQueryTableViewController that runs a query sorting through the ShowAssignments table looking for all rows that belong to the current user. Then, I want to display the Name of each Show (the Show table has a Name field) in the cells of the table.

Here is my code:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "ShowAssignments"
        self.textKey = "Show.Name"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "ShowAssignments")
        query.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        query.includeKey("Show")

        return query
    }
```

This seems like it is grabbing the correct ShowAssignment rows, but the value in the cell is showing null instead of the Name.

** edit **

Now, trying this to set the text by overriding cellForRowAtIndexPath..

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath         indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
let CellIdentifier: String = "myShowCell"

        var cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as?     PFTableViewCell

        if cell != nil
        {
            var obj: PFObject! = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            var show: PFRelation! = obj.relationForKey("Show")

            cell?.textLabel?.text = show.valueForKey("Name") as? String
        }

        return cell
}
```

This doesn't seem to be the right way to do it though. Am I using PFRelation correctly?

**** edit ****

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

        var cellIdentifier: String = "myShowCell"

        var cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:     indexPath) as PFTableViewCell

        var relation: PFRelation = object.relationForKey("Show")
        cell.textLabel?.text = relation.valueForKey("Name") as String

        return cell as PFTableViewCell
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the code they use to display the name of the cell, I'm beginning to doubt whether it can handle relations. All they do is to call `objectForKey:`, and I don't know if that is capable of returning data through a relation. You may have to override the `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: object:` and use the `relationForKey` method to get the relation object then pull the `Name` field from that.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense and is probably what I'm going to have to do. I added what I'm trying now to my original post, I'm running in to a bit more trouble now in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Could you guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. Here is my solution now for those interested.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "UserShowAssignments"
        self.textKey = "Show"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,     cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) ->     PFTableViewCell! {

        var cellIdentifier: String = "myShowCell"

        var cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:     indexPath) as PFTableViewCell

        var show: PFObject = object.objectForKey("Show") as PFObject
        cell.textLabel?.text = show.valueForKeyPath("Name") as? String

        return cell as PFTableViewCell
    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "UserShowAssignments")
        query.whereKey("User", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
        query.includeKey("Show")

        return query
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pretty close. You haven't implemented the last method correctly, however. If the dequeue method actually returns an object other than nil, you never set the text property.

First off, there is no reason to use a PFTableViewCell unless you are doing image loading from parse, as that is all that class does.

Second, I'd recommend switching to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` which is guaranteed to return a new instance of a cell, so you avoid the nil check.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(GLBarcodeItem *)object {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell is guaranteed to be initialized

    PFRelation *relation = [object relationForKey:@"Show"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [relation valueForKey:@"Name"];

    return cell;
}
```

My best attempt at the same Swift method.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {
    var cellIdentifier: String = "myShowCell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:indexPath) as PFTableViewCell

    var relation = object.relationForKey("Show")
    cell.textLabel.text = relation.valueForKey("Name")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hey, I just added what I have now to my original post... I feel like I'm really close, but this still doesn't seem to work. The debugger shows it dropping out on the line where I'm trying to set the text of the cell's label and now the table doesn't load anything.

Comment: Hmm, looks correct to me, but I'm not a parse expert by any means. Maybe try changing the type of the cell from a PFTableViewCell to an UITableViewCell?

Comment: added my best attempt at the same swift method - may have some errors but it's the closest to what I would do in my code

Comment: It's forcing me to use PFTableViewCell since I'm inheriting from PFQueryTableViewController.. I don't think that's the issue though. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I figured it out. We were really close. I'm not sure if my solution is the optimal solution, but hey, it works.. I'm posting it now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Cool, any idea what the original problem was then?

Comment: Instead of grabbing the PFRelation, I just took the PFObject that the relation pointed to by using object.objectForKey.